# Помогите найти датасет для предсказания уйдет ли клиент от страховщика

Tags: машинное-обучение, big-data, scikit-learn

Доброго времени суток! Есть цель - по имеющимся данным клиента предсказывать уйдет ли он от страховой компании через год (возможно 1, 2, 3), допустим страхование в сфере имущества - дома, квартиры. На основании датасета хотелось бы выделить ряд признаков и протестировать на валидационной выборке точность предсказания. Буду премного благодарен, если поможете

Comment: Про наборы данных лучше спросить здесь: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/